# Cloudflare - Shortcut to block all countries and whitelist just one or two

Tags: cloudflare

Hi I am looking for a shortcut(using cloudflare and cloudflare firewall page) to block all countries and whitelist only a few.

I can manually create block lists for all the countries but there are so many countries that adding them manually would be a time intensive task.

Yes, I can do this via some other code, but this question aims at looking for a shortcut at this moment. I know there is an IP range but how do I execute(block) all and then override the block by whitelisting a few countries manually.

Answer (score -1):

I found [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1506532) discussion on the internet.
It's quite old (5 years ago) but it seems that this feature it's still not available.
So nasty :(